# Android - Alarm manager runs every day

Tags: android

I don't understand what's wrong but my alarm runs every single day even if I hardcode the day number, I have no idea whats going on...

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(AddTask.this,CustomBroadcastReceiver.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_UID,newTaskId);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddTask.this, newTaskId, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,2);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);
```

today is sunday so the day number is 1 and i wrote  calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,2); and the alarm just got trigered since i used the time and minute of this moment... it doesnot matter if i set the day number 1 2 3 4 5 or 6 or even if i make several alarm managers with same ID and each contains other day it triggers every day

Answer (score 1):

Why is this line necessary?

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Also, the android development [documentation](http://[documentation][1]%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) recommends using

```
setInexactRepeating(int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation);
```

EDIT:
I suspect the intent isn't set for creating alarms so it's not creating the alarms correctly.
Maybe this would work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
//set repeating alarm here
```

I hope that answers the question.

Comment: it doesnot i set the alarm day to 3 and number of today is 1 and it just triggered.  i have changed the things as you said

Comment: @uplnypan Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, im sad... i have no idea whats wrong i just want to repeat alarm on given time and day of week forever , until the alarm gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

So okay i have solved this , for everyone who want to create an alarm application like this > you set the time and hour and the days of week to trigger the alarm, it works like this : if today is the day which you choosed you just set the alarm with this :

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
```

but IF the day you picked is not the day which is today you have to the the date of the nearest day you picked and then just set the additional hour and minute as above.

this is the only way to make it work